# How to implement custom actuator endpoint to check zookeeper health?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I would like to implement a custom endpoint class to check Zookeeper health:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/zookeeper
```

PROBLEM: Do I extend AbstractHealthIndicaitor or implement HealthIndicator class?

**HealthIndicator class**

```
public class CustomHealth implements HealthIndicator {

 @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down()
              .withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    public int check() {
        // Our logic to check zookeeper health
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**AbstractHealthIndicator class**

```
public class CustomHealth extends AbstractHealthIndicator  {

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception 
    {
        // Our logic to check zookeeper health
    }

}
```

I'm confused on which approach to use. I believe the logic to check zookeeper health is to simply declare an CuratorFramework object then do curator.getState() and return builder from there and for endpoint, attach @RestControllerEndPoint to declare the path. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you which one to choose, the difference is that `AbstractHealthIndicator`:

1. Provides you with the Health.Builder instance so you don't need to create one manually
2. Wraps `doHealthCheck(builder)` call with try-catch, that returns status DOWN if your healthcheck has failed with exception.

So in general the `AbstractHealthIndicator` is more convenient to use as you can skip error handling. Choose implementing raw `HealthIndicator` when you need to provide custom status details on exception.

For example of Zookeeper Health Indicator please refer to existing one provided with spring-cloud-zookeeper https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/spring-cloud-zookeeper-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/ZookeeperHealthIndicator.java

Regarding the endpoint `/actuator/health/zookeeper`, I suggest you to use new feature introduced in SpringBoot 2.2.0 called **Health Indicator Groups** https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/16/spring-boot-2-2-0#health-indicator-groups

In short, if you use component scan and named custom health indicator `MyZookeeperHealthIndicator`, then add following properties to register it under custom `zookeeper` group:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.zookeeper.include=myZookeeper
```

After that, custom health details will be displayed under `myZookeeper` component at `/actuator/health/zookeeper`

Check following docs for more information:

**Writing Custom HealthIndicators** https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators

**Health Groups** https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#health-groups

Comment: Hi @YuriiJ, although i upvoted your answer as the approach seems logical, did you find a better and simpler approach, 1 month later? ;-)

Comment: Hi @jumping_monkey. Well, the initial problem was in choosing whether to implement *HealthIndicator* or extend *AbstractHealthIndicator* and I believe there is _correct_ recommendation in my answer :) What do you mean when saying _better_ and _simpler_, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: If you're asking about Zookeeper then checking CuratorFramework state along with existence of ZNode as in SpringCloud Zookeeper HealthIndicator seems enough. Also please note that you're not checking the _Zookeeper health itself_, but rather _an ability of your service instance to connect to it_ - imagine that suddenly happened a network partition leaving your service isolated from healthy Zookeeper cluster which is accessible from other places.